# Counting the size of multiple collection in Mongodb with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to count the number of documents inside two collections (Devices, Rooms). I saved details inside Devices schema and Rooms Schema as separate collections. How to query both the collections and return the count of documents?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `count()`:

```
var devicesCountQuery = DevicesModel.count();
var roomsCountQuery   = RoomsModel.count();
```

With mongo you have to do two single queries.

You can wrap it in a single call using `Promise.all()` (Mongoose supports promises):

```
Promise.all([
  DevicesModel.count().exec(),
  RoomsModel.count().exec()
]).then(function(counts) {
  console.log('Devices count %d', counts[0]);
  console.log('Rooms count %d', counts[1]);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it inside single function?